# selfの参照について

Tags: swift

```
class Hoge {
    var a: Int

    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a // (1)
    }

    var b: Int {
        return self.a // (2)
    }

    func c() -> Int {
        return self.a // (3)
    }

    var d = { self.a * 2 }()  // (4)
}
```

上記コードで、(1),(2),(3)のselfは正しく自分を参照しますが、(4)は以下エラーが表示されます。

```
<stdin>:17:19: error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
var d = { self.a * 2 }() // (4)
^
```

また、selfを外し、

```
var d = { a * 2 }()  // (4)
```

とすると、以下エラーが表示されます。

```
<stdin>:17:19: error: 'Hoge.Type' does not have a member named 'a'
var d = { a * 2 }() // (4)
^
```

実行環境は、以下になるのですが、この環境のバグでしょうか？
それとも、何か間違っているのでしょうか？

http://swiftstub.com/

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: lazy var d = { self.a * 2 }() // (4)
とすることで、エラーがでなくなりました。「lazy」は、実際に参照する際にdが生成されるということなので、その時は確かにselfはありますよね。だからエラーがでなくなったということなのでしょうが、ではそれ以外の(1)～(3)のselfはどう説明できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiftの言語仕様上、参照型の`self`へアクセスできるタイミングは決まっているためだと思います。

> **Safety check 4**
>   An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete.
>
> [Initialization - The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

初期化処理の第一段階が完了するまでは、`self`は無効な識別子です。これはベースクラスのプロパティが初期化されていない、不定状態のインスタンスへアクセスする可能性を防ぐためです。

---

また、その記述が合法だとすると、別な問題がありえます。

クロージャが参照型であり、プロパティはARCによるメモリ管理がされることを考えると、`self`とクロージャは互いに強参照し、循環参照となり、一度生成したインスタンスは絶対に解放されないことになります。

この問題は遅延初期化プロパティにしていても変わらないため、

```
lazy var d :() -> Int = {
    [unowned self] in
    self.a * 2
}
```

と書くのが望ましいです。